# Confusing transformation into compound sentences

Tags: transformation

What would be the transformation of the following sentences into compound sentences?

"If you want success , you will have to do be diligent."

"If I didn't help him, he wouldn't pass the exam."

MY ASSUMPTION:

"You want success and so you will have to be diligent."

"I didn't help him and so he wouldn't pass the exam."

I'm not so sure of the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is easy, I'd reverse the order though, so...

> You have to be diligent if you want success.

For the second, get rid of the two negatives, it makes any compound sentence difficult to read.  I'd simply say

> I need to help him pass his exam.

or perhaps simpler using new words

> I need to help him study for his exam.